# Add new line to list if key already exist

Tags: java, hashmap

I have to build hashMap that contain key object and list of instances that related to this key.
during the build of the map I want to ask if the key object(vocKey) already exist don't create new instance 
for Voc key just add new line to the list of vocData ,how I can do that ?

```
private HashMap<vocKey,List<vocData>> vocabulary = new HashMap<vocKey,List<vocData>>();
```

Comment: `if(vocabulary.get(key) == null) { //exists }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [HashMap.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
List<vocData> data = vocabulary.get(key);
if (data == null) {
    vocabulary.put(...);
} else {
    data.add(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guide. Give it a try yourself

```
 1) First get the value using key.
 2) if a value exist add new line to value list
 3) if value does not exist create a new instance and add under new key.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<vocData> data = vocabulary.get(key);
if (data == null) {
    data = new ArrayList();
    vocabulary.put(key, data);
} 
data.add(...);
```